# ABAP Code_Scanner / RS_ABAP_SOURCE_SCAN timeout

Tags: abap

I am using `code_scanner` transaction code to find a string, however, it times out.

I restrict the query and find code where Package = Z*

This helps me to search only the code modified at the customer end.

I want to search in SAP code like SAP Function Modules, Executable Programs, Menu, Class, Objects, Corrections, and Modifications without timeout.

How should I restrict the query to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can run the program in the background and it won't timeout. However still might take a long time...

Comment: FYI my 2 cents, looking at all SAP programs will probably takes days, also not sure to understand the need, I never had to do that in 20 years working in ABAP software.

Comment: @SandraRossi Oh it's a super useful feature. But only with [ABAP Source Search](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_751_IP/c238d694b825421f940829321ffa326a/4ec78e866e391014adc9fffe4e204223.html?version=7.51.1). With HANA it took at most a few seconds, and you could find usage examples, comment, t100 message etc super easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran the program with a comparable query in one of our development systems and got the results in less than a minute. So when you get a timeout then you either have a lot of custom code in that system or a very slow system.

Anyway, what you can do in such a case is execute the program as a background process. Instead of clicking the "Execute" button, go to Program -> Execute in Background. You can then monitor the process of that background job using the transaction SM37 and once it's finished you can look at the "spool list" (its text output). The text output won't be interactive (you can't navigate using double-click), but it should contain the information you need to navigate to the program lines manually.